# Parse Query Contains Non-Exact String

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform

In my Parse Class, I have a column of `Names`. I would like to query for all names that contain `searchString = "om"`. The query should return all names that contain "om" such as `Tom, Dom, Rom, etc.)

I've tried:

```
searchString = "om" // something non-exact
var query = PFQuery(className: "NamesClass")
query.whereKey("Name", contains: searchString)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
```

but Parse doesn't accept `contains` as a search parameter.

Seems like queries only accept exact strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For substring matching, you should be using `whereKey:containsString:`

```
searchString = "om" 
var query = PFQuery(className: "NamesClass")
query.whereKey("Name", containsString: searchString)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
```

That should return any `NamesClass` object where `Name` has a substring equal to "om". So, Tom, Dominique, and Thomas will be returned. Frank won't.

Comment: You've made my day. This should be printed in caps in the Parse Doc.